# Use variable in Teamcity build config name

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I'd like to include a variable value in the TeamCity config name.

For example, if my config is called `[Patch release 4.3] - quick build`, I'd like the "4.3" to be taken from a variable, e.g `%release.number%`.

Answer (score 1):

References are not supported in the names at least at this time (TeamCity 7.x).
See/vote for the corresponding [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-22608).

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to use a powershell script to update the Name via the REST interface

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain")
$wc.UploadString("http://myserver/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:<build_id>/name","Put","%branch_name%")
```

see "Project Settings" at http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin